# Trouble with javax.crypto.Cipher

Tags: java, exception, encryption

I have imported the following into my project

```
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.io.*;
```

The following is telling me "Unhandled exception type NoSuchPaddingException"

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

I'm using JaveSE-1.6.

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: YOU need to throw Exception.

Comment: Since you haven't specified the padding you would be getting the default padding, in which case this exception should be impossible. To me this suggests you have really messed up some part of the crypto configuration, either your class path is wrong or you have installed a buggy provider somewhere. Java 1.6 out of the box running this code won't throw that exception.

Answer (score 5):

`Cipher.getInstance(...)` throws two kinds of exceptions, and requires that you handle them.

Either have the method containing `Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");` rethrow the exception if you wish to handle it elsewhere:

`public void foo(){ throws Exception
...
}`

Or better yet, enclose the method in a try-catch block:

```
try{
   Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
}
catch(Exception e){
   //do something about it
}
```

You can also get fancier and do this:

```
try{
   Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
}
catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
   //handle the case of having no matching algorithm
}
catch(NoSuchPaddingException e){
   //handle the case of a padding problem
}
```

Certain Java methods throw exceptions, and some of these require that you handle them. Anything in the Java API docs with `Throws` after the method requires handling. Generally there is a good reason they make you do this. In this case, if you can't get the correct cipher, you can't encrypt anything.

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to mark this question as answered if you feel it is complete.

Comment: The reason for this Exception to be thrown is that the compiler does not check the contents of the String. If it did then it would be able to determine that the String was valid and not throw an exception. It would be nicer if the API would have a way to do this, it is certainly possible. For now we are stuck handling the GeneralSecurityExceptions though.